# How do I get Particle Boids to fight each other?

Tags: particles

In the Boid Brain there is a option called 'Fight' so how do I set up a scene where two groups of Boids fight each other? Or am I misunderstanding something here?

If you have a link for a tutorial that would be good.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can make groups of boid particles fight.

For a basic setup:

1. Add two emitters with separate particle systems.
2. Set each particle system as the enemy of the other, and with fighting as a priority:

   [image]

Result:

[image]

Also see the [wiki](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Doc:2.6/Manual/Physics/Particles/Physics/Boids#Battle) for more info.

Answer (score 2):

You need to define at least 2 particle systems with a relation *enemy* to each other, you can define attributes like strength (this will statistically decide who wins [particle disappears when defeated]).

You could add *Follow Leader* to the boids brain and animate the leader, this would make the particles follow the leader (creates nice formations). There're so many options you need to play around and develop an idea of how it should like.

[image]

In the physics settings make sure you checked *Allow Flight* or restrict them to land.

[image]

I stopped playing with this because I wasn't able to create explosions when a particle dies.

Example:

[image]

Comment: I hope it doesn't look like I'm stealing your answer.. I had already started writing it when you posted yours. On the up side, this will help with our answer ratio :D

Comment: @gandalf3 not at all, I'm rather concerned that this will be closed.